# Why am I getting 'Cannot invoke java.lang.Class.isInterface()' error during Vaadin 24 packaging in production mode?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

Vaadin 24 - Production mode on : Error on build-frontend when packaging / Cannot invoke "java.lang.Class.isInterface()"

While application is running well when started with spring-boot:run, we cannot achieve package goal.

Following error is showing on build-frontend phase :

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.vaadin:vaadin-maven-plugin:24.0.5:build-frontend (default-cli) on project myproj: Could not execute build-frontend goal: Error occured during goal execution: Cannot invoke "java.lang.Class.isInterface()" because the return value of "org.reflections.Reflections.forClass(String, java.lang.ClassLoader[])" is nullPlease run Maven with the -e switch (or Gradle with the --stacktrace switch), to learn the full stack trace. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

POM is quite basic, with cfg :

```
<properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <vaadin.version>24.0.5</vaadin.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
</properties>
```

Executing goals with JDK17

Error only shows up with production profile. Works well without.
I found same error report on earlier Vaadin versions, solved adding --enable-preview, but not working here with JDK17 / Vaadin24

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As part of the production build, the classpath is scanned for classes for certain annotations such as `@JsModule`. This is to be able to create the JavaScript bundle used in the final application.

What is done is basically:

1. Set up a class loader for all available classes
2. Use the `reflections` library to find types annotated with e.g. `@JsModule`
3. Gather the values from all `@JsModule` annotations and build a JavaScript bundle

Step 2 is the one that goes wrong here, and in the way that a class with a given annotation is found, but then when trying to load the class, it cannot be loaded.

As you mentioned, one problem might be that the class uses preview features and you have not enabled preview features for the production build. Another case described in https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/16577 is that a dependency jar compiled with a newer JDK was included.

You should be able to find the offending class by running the Maven target in an IDE in debug mode and adding a `NullPointerException` breakpoint. Then it might become clear what the actual problem is.

Comment: NullPointerException breakpoint did the job, I was able to find the defect add-on. Many thx !

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this issue also this morning. Code compiled just fine. Only the vaadin-maven-plugin failed.

Tried Arthur's suggestion to debug the compile process. This did give me the answer which page class was causing the issue. However, I still want to be able to use preview features and not be constraint to not be able to use them in some classes.

So I had to figure out how and where to add the missing `--enable-preview` flag since the compiler clearly had that setting already and the vaadin plugin has no way to add it.

I figured that the Maven java process should be started with the `--enable-preview` setting so this would be set in the process when the Vaadin maven plugin needs to do its work.
There are, of course, multiple ways to do this.

- setting `export JAVA_OPTS="--enable-preview"` does not work
- setting `export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="--enable-preview"` does work, but not easy to persist with the project.

Eventually settled on adding a `.mvn/jvm.config` file with contents `--enable-preview` to the project. This gets picked up by Maven (see [configurating Maven](https://maven.apache.org/configure.html#mvn-jvm-config-file)) and is easy to check in Git so everyone has it.

With this we're able to use Java (21) preview features in Vaadin page classes.